# Run a SSIS Job for Specific Amount of Time Without Using Scheduler

Tags: c#, .net, ssis, ssrs-2012, ssis-2008

I have a requirement wherein I have to Run a SSIS Job for only 2 Hours.
Now this Job Could be started anytime of the Day, but after 2 Hours It should Automatically Stop.

Can this be achieved using SSIS?
Is there any way I could go ahead with this?

Comment: See following : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/90204a2a-1ee8-4807-a333-6fa74ef2e532/ssishow-to-set-timeout-for-the-whole-package-or-sequence-container?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Is it a SSIS project in Visual Studio? If so, you can use Windows tasks or scheduler

Comment: @GHDevOps I am aware about the Scheduler Option But wanted to find if there is any alternative to implement this from the Package itself.

Comment: You could have a step in your job as step 1 that for step 1 for this job, it schedules a 2nd job (you already have setup) but adds a schedule to run 2 hours from that time, that will kill this job if still running.